# Construct a ring containing $16$ element where EVERY element $r\neq 0$,$1$ is a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a practice question to prepare me for my final exam in abstract algebra.

Construct a ring containing $16$ elements where EVERY element $r\neq 0$,$1$ is a zero divisor

I'm having a hard time starting this out. Especially, how can I ensure a ring I create has 16 elements. My first thought it to create a quotient ring R/I.

Since we're restricting our ring to have exactly 16 elements, it, of course, has to be finite.

I'm not the best at abstract algebra so this may not be even close, but here is one I thought would work:

Let $R = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{32} |$ a is even, $a > 0\}$ and let $I = 2$.

So then $R = \{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32\}$ which has 16 elements, and since we're modding out by 2, they're all zero divisors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that your example is not a ring because there’s no $1$.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^4$. We can identify this ring with the collection of subsets of $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ by using indicator functions. Then addition is symmetric difference and multiplication is intersection. The null set is $0$, and $X$ is the identity. For any subset $S\subseteq X$, we then have $S\cdot S^C=0$. Thus either $S=\varnothing=0$, $S=X=1$, or $S$ is a zero divisor.

**Edit**

The ring I suggest is the following. It is the set of 4-tuples of whose entries are either $0$ or $1$.

Some example elements of this ring are $(0,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1,1)$, and $(1,1,1,1)$. Since there are two choices for each entry, there are 16 total elements.

The ring operations are pointwise addition and multiplication where $1+1=0$ and otherwise addition and multiplication behave normally (i.e. $0\cdot 1=0$, $1\cdot 1=1$, $0\cdot 0=0$, and $0+0=0$, and $1+0=1$). As examples,
$$(0,1,1,0)+(1,0,1,1)=(0+1,1+0,1+1,0+1)=(1,1,0,1),$$
and
$$(0,1,1,0)\cdot (1,0,1,1)=(0\cdot 1,1\cdot 0, 1\cdot 1,0\cdot 1)=(0,0,1,0).$$

You can check that $(0,0,0,0)$ is the additive identity and $(1,1,1,1)$ is the multiplicative identity.

Then if $(a,b,c,d)$ is a tuple that is not one of these, if we define a new tuple 
$(\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c},\bar{d})$ by making $\bar{0}=1$ and $\bar{1}=0$, then
$0\cdot \bar{0}=0\cdot 1=0$ and $1\cdot \bar{1}=1\cdot 0=0$, so 
$$(a,b,c,d)\cdot (\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c},\bar{d})=
(a\bar{a},b\bar{b},c\bar{c},d\bar{d})
=(0,0,0,0).$$
Thus all nonzero elements are zero divisors in this ring.

Comment: This coincides with coordinate-wise addition and multiplication, right? This might be easier to see

Comment: @platty, yes that's what I started with. I just think it simplifies the argument that every nonzero nonone element is a zero divisor to identify it subsets.

Comment: To be honest, we have not seen rings with exponents, nor have I heard of an indicator function. This looks very foreign. Perhaps I'm not well versed enough to get an answer I'll understand on StackExchange. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @Mari Sorry, I'll try to explain it a bit more clearly.

Comment: Oh, I see. Of course, we've seen rings raised to powers... Really the only one I have seen is $\R^2$, so that's the reason the exponent of 4 threw me off. That makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much. We definitely haven't done a proof quite like this, but I understand where everything is coming from... Do you have any advice on thinking through these kinds of problems? I have other problems asking me to construct rings containing 16 elements that I can try.

Comment: @Mari No worries. It's hard to say exactly what advice I can give. Perhaps I'd suggest, in situations like this where you know the ring is going to be finite, then it's *probably* (certainly not always) either the integers mod some number, or some product of rings that are the integers mod some numbers, or (if it is noncommutative) *maybe* a matrix ring over the integers mod some number. And I suppose it's clear that your thought was indeed the integers mod 32, so that was good intuition in some ways. It's hard to give advice though, since much of it is a product of experience.

Comment: @jgon It seems like experience is the key. Would you mind explaining why my constructed ring is incorrect though?

Comment: @Mari Oh sorry, yes. A couple issues, the first is that your $R$ has 16 elements to start with, and you then mod out by $I$, which is going to reduce the number of elements, so $R/I$ won't have 16 elements like you want. Also if $I$ is the ideal generated by 2, then since every element of $R$ is divisible by 2, $R/I$ will be the zero ring. Also $R$ doesn't have a unit.

Comment: @jgon How could my R have a unit if every element is a zero divisor? If every element is a zero divisor, none of them can be units.

Comment: @Mari Yes, that's one reason why it doesn't have a unit. But the problem asks you to find a ring with a 1, which is why I said it was a problem with your ring.

Answer (score 0):

In a finite commutative ring $R$, every noninvertible element is a zero divisor.

Indeed, if $r$ is not invertible, the map $x\mapsto rx$ is not surjective (because $1$ is missed), so it is not injective. Being a group homomorphism with respect to addition, its kernel is nonzero, which proves the claim.

Your ring must have a single invertible element, hence its characteristic needs to be $2$: indeed, $-1$ is invertible, so we need $-1=1$.

Thus $R$ has to be a four dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and it's quite natural to look for a ring structure on $\mathbb{F}_2^4$.

One possibility is the product ring, which indeed satisfies the requirement, because an element of the form $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ where one of the entries is zero is surely a zero divisor: if $e_i$ denotes the $4$-tuple with $1$ at the $i$-th place an zero elsewhere, then $a_i=0$ implies $ae_i=0$.